# use template to instead preprocessor?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

There are 2 classes, most code is same.

```
template<typename T>
class A1 {
f1(){common code... do_with(_m) ... common code}
f2();
fn();
T _m;
};

template<typename T>
class A2 {
f1(){common code... do_with(_m, _b) ... common code}
f2();
fn();
B _b;
std::atomic<T*> _m;
};
```

Because 95% code is same, I want to make those 2 class into one, but I can not use preprocessor due to both of them will be used in one project. And because these 2 class is template, so I can not use "template method" design pattern to extract same code into a base class and leave some private virtual function to derived class to override.

Is it possible to avoid code duplication? For example:

```
A<T, type_a1> a1;
A<T, type_a2> a2;
```

I have considered template specialization, but it can not support "extract the common part of code", a specialized class have to rewrite whole function

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
template <typename T>
void common_f1_pre(T& t) { ... }

template <typename T>
void common_f1_post(T& t) { ... }
```

In A1:

```
f1(){common_f1_pre(_m);  do_with(_m); common_f1_post(_m); }
```

In A2:

```
f1(){common_f1_pre(_m);  do_with(_m, _b); common_f1_post(_m); }
```

**Method 2**

```
template <typename A>
void common_f1(A& a)
{
  // Common to A1 and A2  ... }

  a.f1_core();

  // Common to A1 and A2 
}
```

In A1:

```
f1(){f1_common(*this);}
f1_core() {do_with(_m);}
```

In A2:

```
f1(){f1_common(*this);}
f1_core() {do_with(_m, _b);}
```